# PHP Still give me old data after form submit

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have form for updating some data on my category table. After i post my new data via form, page refresh but it still show old data to me.

```
public function updateCategory($status, $main_category, $title, $bg_color, $meta_title, $meta_description, $meta_keywords, $id)
{
    $sql = "UPDATE categories SET status = ?, main_category = ? , title = ?, bg_color = ?, meta_title = ?, meta_description = ?, meta_keywords = ? WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    try {
            $stmt->execute([$status, $main_category, $title, $bg_color, $meta_title, $meta_description, $meta_keywords, $id]);
            return true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    return false;
    }
}
```

Form post area

```
 $category = new Categories();
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $query = $category->getCategoryDetails($id);
 $result = false;
 if (isset($_POST['categorySave'])) {

    $result = $category->updateCategory($_POST['status'],$_POST['main_category'],$_POST['title'],$_POST['bg_color'],$_POST['meta_title'],$_POST['meta_description'], $_POST['meta_keywords'], $query->id);

}
?>
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php if ($result) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        <?=UPDATESUCCESS?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
<label for="title">Başlık</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Başlık" value="<?=$query->title?>">
        ...
```

Its update data without problem. As an example if i change title 'Title New', it updates on my database. But after form submit, it stay as the same. 'Title Old'

Comment: If you getCategoryDetail AFTER you do the update, you will see the new data. The way you have it now you fetch all the old data... run the update... and the show the old date you selected

Comment: Not sure what this does `<?=UPDATESUCCESS?>` unless you have defined `UPDATESUCCESS` somewhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

move update code above the get code.

```
$result = false;
if (isset($_POST['categorySave'])) {
    $result = $category->updateCategory($_POST['status'],$_POST['main_category'],$_POST['title'],$_POST['bg_color'],$_POST['meta_title'],$_POST['meta_description'], $_POST['meta_keywords'], $query->id);
}

$category = new Categories();
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = $category->getCategoryDetails($id);

?>
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php if ($result) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        <?=UPDATESUCCESS?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
<label for="title">Başlık</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Başlık" value="<?=$query->title?>">
        ...
```